# Operation on lists as elements of dataframe in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a time series by ID, and list of the dates at which an event occurred.  I want to know how many times the event has happened by a given date within my time series.

Here is a sample dataframe:

```
ID <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
date <- c(2000,2001,2002)
df <- data.frame(ID,date)

rand1 <- c(runif(5)*4+1999)
rand2 <- c(runif(6)*4+1999)
rand3 <- c(runif(100)*4+1999)

df$events <- list(rand1, rand1, rand1, rand2, rand2, rand2,rand3, rand3, rand3 )
```

This code does solve my problem correctly:

```
for (i in c(1:9)){
  print(i)
  df[i,]$past <- sum( df[i,]$events[[1]] < df[i,]$date)
}
```

But it seems wildly inefficient to go line by line through a dataframe.  My real dataset has 4 million rows, so I need something a little more sensible.

Here is what I tried first: I'm not sure exactly what it's doing, but it ends up creating all elements of df$past2 as some integer.

```
df$past2 <- sum(df$events[[1]] < df$date)
```

Resulting df:

```
ID  date        events   past past2
<dbl> <dbl>     <list>  <dbl> <int>
1   2000      <dbl [5]>   3     6
1   2001      <dbl [5]>   3     6
1   2002      <dbl [5]>   4     6
2   2000      <dbl [6]>   0     6
2   2001      <dbl [6]>   3     6
2   2002      <dbl [6]>   5     6
3   2000    <dbl [100]>  26     6
3   2001    <dbl [100]>  55     6
3   2002    <dbl [100]>  74     6
```

So,

1) what is my `df$past2` calculation really doing?

2) Is there a way to do this kind of operation on lists that are elements of a dataframe without going line by line?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your df$past2 is that `df$events[[1]]` always return `df[1,]$df$events[[1]]`.

One solution to your problem is to split each row of your dataframe into a list and use lapply:

```
df$past2 = unlist(lapply(split(df,seq(nrow(df))),function(x) sum(x$events[[1]]< x$date)))
```

However, because there is some data manipulation, I am not sure that this is very efficient with a 4 million lines dataframe. You might need to look into `data.table` or `dplyr`to find a more efficient solution.

Answer (score 2):

1) Your `df$past2` calculation is returning the number of rows where the FIRST value of the events list is less than value in the date column, and then sets the entire column to this value. The expression in the brackets returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` and is interpreted as 
`1` or `0` when you call `sum()`. For example `sum(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)` returns `2`.

2) Using the `tidyr::unnest()` function as well as functions from the `dplyr` package, you could do the following:

```
df2 <- df %>%
  unnest(events) %>%
  group_by(ID, date) %>%
  mutate(past = if_else(events < date, 1, 0)) %>%
  summarize(past2 = sum(past))
```

Comment: Both this answer, and @xraynaud's answer work on my example problem, but based on the microbenchmark results for the two approaches, this one is 100x faster.   editing to add that my units for the same code wasn't the same...  rechecking and ill update when I have the units correct.

Comment: Ok, after getting my units correct:   unlist has a mean time of 732 microseconds, and unnest has a mean time of 4060 microseconds.  The code for this approach is a lot easier to read and understand, so I think it's probably the right choice in a lot of cases.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `tidyr::unnest()` to create one row per event, then `dplyr::filter()` for the events that occured after the dates of interest.